# how to get all the keys in a 2d dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of form:

```
d = {123:{2:1,3:1}, 124:{3:1}, 125:{2:1},126:{1:1}}
```

So, lets look into 2nd degree keys..

```
123--> 2,3
124--> 3
125--> 2
126--> 1
```

So total number of unique 2nd order keys are:

```
1,2,3
```

Now, i want to modify this dict as

```
 d = {123:{1:0,2:1,3:1}, 124:{1:0,2:0,3:1}, 125:{1:0,2:1,3:0},126:{1:1,2:0,3:0}}
```

So basically all the 2nd order keys absent in a particular 2d dict.. add that key with value 0.

What is the pythonic way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
keyset = set()
for k in d:
    keyset.update(d[k])

for k in d:
    for kk in keyset:
        d[k].setdefault(kk, 0)
```

Comment: +1.  Simple and readable.  A good reminder not to do too much on one line.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [25]: d = {123:{2:1,3:1}, 124:{3:1}, 125:{2:1},126:{1:1}}

In [26]: se=set(y for x in d for y in d[x])

In [27]: for x in d:
    foo=se.difference(d[x])
    d[x].update(dict(zip(foo,[0]*len(foo))))
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [30]: d
Out[30]: 
{123: {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1},
 124: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1},
 125: {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0},
 126: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0}}
```

here use set difference to get the missing keys and then `update()` the dict:

```
In [39]: for x in d:
    foo=se.difference(d[x])
    print foo                # missing keys per dict
set([1])
set([1, 2])
set([1, 3])
set([2, 3])
```

Comment: No need to cast the results of `zip` to a `dict`.  `update` can handle a list of two item tuples.

Comment: To my mind, it would be even more Pythonic if `set(key2 for key,value in d.iteritems() for key2 in value)` be used. Also, there is no need to construct `dict` in `d[x].update(dict(zip(foo,[0]*len(foo))))` as `update` can take just iterator, so `d[x].update(zip(foo,[0]*len(foo)))` will do, also, `d[x]` here could also be replaced with `value` if `iteritems()` is used.

Answer (score 2):

I like the solution of Ashwini Chaudhary.

I edited it to incorporate all the suggestions in the comments with other minor changes for it to look how I would prefer it:

***Edited** (incorporates the suggestion of Steven Rumbalski to this answer).*

```
all_second_keys = set(key for value in d.itervalues() for key in value)

for value in d.itervalues():
    value.update((key,0) for key in all_second_keys if key not in value)
```

Comment: I would change the first line to `all_second_keys = set(key for value in d.itervalues() for key in value)`.

Comment: Second line to: `for value in d.itervalues(): value.update((key,0) for key in all_second_keys.difference(value))`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you! I updated the answer. I only didn't alter `...for key in all_second_keys if key not in value` to `for key in all_second_keys.difference(value)`. Their time complexity is the same, but I like it more the way I left it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

second_order_keys = reduce(operator.__or__,
                           (set(v.iterkeys()) for v in d.itervalues()))
for v in d.itervalues():
    for k in second_order_keys:
        v.setdefault(k, 0)
```

Or, in Python 3:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

second_order_keys = reduce(operator.__or__,
                           (v.keys() for v in d.values()))
for v in d.values():
    for k in second_order_keys:
        v.setdefault(k, 0)
```

Comment: I had to read your use of `reduce` a few times before I could understand it.  `second_order_keys = set(k for v in d.itervalues() for k in v)` is simpler to me.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski :) I can't still get what `reduce` does there and why the need for `or` operator.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Got it only after a minute. Very convoluted indeed!

Comment: @ovgolovin:  It's very clear to people with a more functional background (not me).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I actually agree, but this is the first version that come to mind and when other people had posted better solutions, I decided to leave it as is. FP happens to be a major part of my day job :)