# finding coordinates in python

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates

so i have this assignment where i'm given a "map"

```
island = \
['     /---------\       ',
 '     |     x    \      ',
 '     /           \--\  ',
 '    /   x            | ',
 '    |         x      | ',
 '     \               \ ',
 '      \  x  /\/\     / ',
 '       \---/    \   |  ',
 '                /--/   ']
```

Write a program that counts the number of treasures on the island (x marks the spot) and creates a list of coordinates, e.g. [(1,11), ...] ((1,11) is the actual location of the top treasure in the example) and then prints out a report in the form: There are 3 treasures. There is a treasure at (1,11). There is a treasure at .... Hint: start with a (very short) expression for the symbol in the ith row and the jth column.

Write a program that calculates the length of the coastline. Assume that an `'-'` and a `'|'` are `1 mile`, and a `'\'`, `'/'` is `1.4 miles`. (This is only a very rough estimate, for many reasons, some of them mathematical).

i'm not even sure where to begin here....can anybody help me out or at the very least point me in the right direction?

Comment: What if treasures are in the sea?

Comment: what's the answer of `length of coastline` question?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `21 + 20*1.4`

Comment: @Eric thanks, got the same answer.

Answer (score 7):

First thing you'll want to do is iterate over the array

```
for column, line in enumerate(island):
    print column, line
```

That gives you

```
0      /---------\       
1      |     x    \      
2      /           \--\  
3     /   x            | 
4     |         x      | 
5      \               \ 
6       \  x  /\/\     / 
7        \---/    \   |  
8                 /--/
```

Ok, so how about iterating horizontally over each row? Exactly the same:

```
for column, line in enumerate(island):
    for row, cell in enumerate(line):
        print "entry at", row, column, "is", cell
```

<sup>Warning: gives long output!</sup>

That should be enough to get you started

Comment: +1 for not giving the exact solution but a good piece of advice as the question is obviously of a homework assignment kind

Comment: +1 for this, plus he can also use dictionary like `{'\\':1.4,'/':1.4,'-':1,'|':1}` to make his job easy, while calculating distance.

Answer (score 1):

Since people are posting complete solutions, here is one that is Pythonic but not advanced.

```
segment_lengths = {'\\':1.4,'/':1.4,'-':1,'|':1}
coast_len = 0
treasure_coords = []
for y, line in enumerate(island):
    for x, c in enumerate(line):
        coast_len += segment_lengths.get(c, 0)
        if c == 'x':
            treasure_coords.append((y, x))
print len(treasure_coords), 'treasures found at', treasure_coords
print 'island coast length is', coast_len
```

Prints:

```
4 treasures found at [(1, 11), (3, 8), (4, 14), (6, 9)]
island coast length is 49.0
```

**edit**:  J.F. Sebastian [offers](http://codepad.org/bdxpmyFQ) an if-elif based solution:

```
coast_length = 0
treasure_coords = []
for y, row in enumerate(island):
    for x, c in enumerate(row):
        if c in r'\/':
            coast_length += 1.4
        elif c in '-|':
            coast_length += 1
        elif c == 'x':
            treasure_coords.append((y, x))

print("There are %d treasures." % (len(treasure_coords),))
for y, x in treasure_coords:
    print("There is a treasure at (%2d, %2d)." % (y, x))
print("The length of the coastline is %.1f." % (coast_length,))
```

Comment: I can go more pythonic: `treasure_coords = [(x, y) for y, row in enumerate(island) for x, c in enumerate(row) if c == 'x']` and `sum(1 if c in ('-', '|') else 1.4 if c in ('/', '\\') else 0 for x in ''.join(island))`

Comment: @Eric:  I avoided the nested list comprehension because it is more advanced.  Also, it means you have to iterate twice, once for the coords, and then again for the coast length.

Comment: Indeed. Yours is probably of the right level of simplicity. Not sure the dictionary is clearer than a pair of ifs here.

Comment: @Eric:  Also, since when is one-liner-itis Pythonic?  (I ask this as one who is a chronic one-liner-itis sufferer.)

Comment: It's the most pythonic thing I can type in the comment box. That makes it pythonic, right?

Comment: my take `sum(segment_lengths.get(y,0) for x in island for y in x)`
and for coords: `[(i,x.index('x')) for i,x in enumerate(island) if 'x' in x]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: fails for `["xx", "x "]`. Made this [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13058283/102441)

Comment: +1 for adequate names (one of the three hard problems in programming :). dict-based solution is preferable but [`elif`-based one can also be readable](http://codepad.org/bdxpmyFQ)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian:  I like your solution so much I added it to my answer.  I like its simplicity.  I think with the wealth of tools in Python simplicity is often overlooked.  See for example all the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960019/how-to-get-all-the-keys-in-a-2d-dict-python).  The accepted answer is pythonic without being complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of posting a (semi-pythonic) solution:

```
# reads as it means - coords where the cell is "x"
treasure_coords = [
    (x, y) for y, row in enumerate(island)
           for x, c in enumerate(row)
           if c == 'x'
]

# slightly more cryptic
coast_length = sum(
    1   if c in '-|'  else
    1.4 if c in '/\\' else
    0
    for c in ''.join(island)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 dimensional grids are pretty easily represented in some sort of an array.  Create an array that stores all of your grid in a way you understand how to lookup what coordinate x,y is in that array.

Check for all the treasures by iterating through the array's indexes.

The coastline is just a perimeter measurement but it's represented much simpler, every character you find is equivalent to some number.  Just run a loop again, looking for these character and when you encounter them, increase some running sum of the coastline.

*You could do all of this in a single loop or in other simple ways...best way for you to do it is to break it up into pieces so you understand how to do this.

Comment: _"The coastline is just a diameter measurement"_ - That's a very strange circle...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do that would be just iterate over every single char (recording the current col/row_ and check it for being 'x' or one of the coast symbols. Like that:

```
length = 0.0
x = 0
y = 0
for line in island:
    x += 1
    y = 0
    for char in line:
        y += 1
        if char == 'x': print 'There is a treasure at (%d,%d)' % (x, y)
        elif char in ('-', '|'):
            length += 1
        elif char in ('\\', '/'):
            length += 1.4
print 'Coast length is', length
```

Of course it doesn't check for treasures in the sea, coast integrity, etc.

Comment: this is very unpythonic, and the co-ordinates returned are also wrong.

Comment: this is pretty useful...however for some reason the coordinates are off by 1?? instead of 1, 11 for example the answer is 2,12...also what would you recommend using to count how many x's? so it says "there are 4 treasures"? i dont think a .count could work, would it?

Comment: coordinates depend on what is the zero point (the 1st character of 1st line). In my case it is 1,1, not 0,0.

And yeah, it is unpythonic but I wanted it to be readable and simple...

As for counting the treasures in "unpythonic" way, just do
`num_treasures += 1` where the treasures are printed out.

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of the coastline, you just need to count the instances of each coast character.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> dict([(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(''.join(island)))])
{' ': 162, '-': 16, '/': 9, '\\': 11, 'x': 4, '|': 5}
```

Then you can add them up:

```
>>> char_counts = dict([(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(''.join(island)))])
>>> char_counts['-'] + char_counts['|'] + 1.4 * (char_counts['/'] + char_counts['\\'])
49.0
```

Comment: Even the OP didn't asked for codes, he wanted some hints not the coded answer.

Comment: Actually he said "Write a program". The last line is pretty clear he wants any help he can get.

Comment: @DRead: That doesn't mean you should do his assignment

Comment: Why not? It might not be ethical for him if he copies my solution, but I'm more interested in answering well the question that is posed.  And I'd hope that good solutions got marked up, rather than vague hints.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic solution for length of coastline part:

```
In [144]: strs
Out[144]: 
['     /---------\\       ',
 '     |     x    \\      ',
 '     /           \\--\\  ',
 '    /   x            | ',
 '    |         x      | ',
 '     \\               \\ ',
 '      \\  x  /\\/\\     / ',
 '       \\---/    \\   |  ',
 '                /--/   ']

In [145]: dic={'\\':1.4,'/':1.4,'-':1,'|':1}

In [146]: sum(dic.get(y,0) for x in strs for y in x)
Out[146]: 48.999999999999979
```

or

```
In [149]: sum(map(lambda x:dic.get(x,0),chain(*strs)))
Out[149]: 48.999999999999979
```

or (As suggested by Eric):

```
In [197]: sum(dic.get(x,0) for x in chain(*strs))
Out[197]: 48.999999999999979
```

for co-ordinates:

```
In [185]: [(i,m.start()) for i,x in enumerate(strs) for m in re.finditer('x',x)]
Out[185]: [(1, 11), (3, 8), (4, 14), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: Think this might cross the pythonic/cryptic boundary. Also, I prefer `sum(dic.get(x,0) for x in chain(*strs))`

Comment: @Eric this one is nice too, and my co-ordinate solution beats yours in timings.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner to python and the problem is quite interesting, my solution to this problem is as follows:
thanks to @Eric for giving an idea for start

```
island = \
['     /---------\       ',
 '     |     x    \      ',
 '     /           \--\  ',
 '    /   x            | ',
 '    |         x      | ',
 '     \               \ ',
 '      \  x  /\/\     / ',
 '       \---/    \   |  ',
 '                /--/   ']
Distance={
    "-":1.0,
    "|":1,
    "\\":1.4,
    "/":1.4
}
Treasure_Location = []
Miles = []
for row, line in enumerate(island):
    #print(row, line)

    for column, cell in enumerate(line):
        if cell== "x":
            Treasure_Location.append((row, column))

        if cell in Distance:
            z=Distance.get(cell)
            Miles.append(z)

Total_miles= sum(Miles)

print ("Co-ordinates of the Treasure in the Island are:\n")
print("\nTreasure 1: " + str(Treasure_Location[0]))
print("\nTreasure 2: " + str(Treasure_Location[1]))
print("\nTreasure 3: " + str(Treasure_Location[2]))
print("\nTreasure 4: " + str(Treasure_Location[3]))
print("\nThe length of the Coastal line is:"+str(Total_miles))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since each line is a value in a list, you can use a simple 'in' check to see if there is a treasure.

```
 for line in island:
     if 'x' in island[line]:
         print '%d,%d' %line,island[line].index('x')
```

Easy way to get your cords.

Comment: why not simply `for line in island`?

Comment: Where did the variable `x` come from?  Did you mean `line`?  What if there are two x's in one row?

Comment: This not exactly right I think. What is the value of `x` in `if 'x' in island[x]`?

Comment: What if there are two x's on the same line? Also, `if 'x' in island` is doing all the work of finding the 'x', then throwing away its position information. That's twice the work necessary.

Comment: Gah, I was meddling around in the shell and I forgot I used random variables....and idk what I was doing in the first line :\